# Python - Issue Scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to scrape the Stack Overflow jobs page using Beautiful Soup 4 and URLLIB as a personal project. I'm facing an issue where I'm trying to scrape all the links to the 50 jobs listed on each page. I'm using a regex to identify these links. Even though I reference the tag properly, I am facing these two specific issues:

1. Instead of the 50 links clearly visible in the source code, I get only 25 results each time as my output(after accounting for an removing an initial irrelevant link)
2. There's a difference between how the links are ordered in the source code and my output.

Here's my code. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated:

```
import bs4
import urllib.request
import re


#Obtaining source code to parse

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab&sort=p&pg=0').read()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

snippet = soup.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json")
strsnippet = str(snippet)

print(strsnippet)

joburls = re.findall('https://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', strsnippet)

print("Urls: ",joburls)
print(len(joburls))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did some [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961049/parsing-a-script-tag-with-dicts-in-beautifulsoup/44961094#44961094) of my own for a part of this answer.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

# note: link is slightly different; yours just redirects here
link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab&sort=p'
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')
urls = [el['url'] for el in json.loads(s.text)['itemListElement']]

print(len(urls))
50
```

Process:

1. Use `soup.find` rather than `soup.find_all`.  This will give a JSON `bs4.element.Tag`
2. `json.loads(s.text)` is a nested dict.  Access the values for `itemListElement` key to get a dict of urls, and convert to list.