# Parsing a script tag with dicts in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

Working on a partial answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957324/python-issue-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/44960710#44960710) question, I came across a `bs4.element.Tag` that is a mess of nested dicts and lists (`s`, below).

Is there a way to return a list of urls contained in `s` *without* using `re.find_all`?  Other comments regarding the structure of this tag are helpful too.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab&sort=p'
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')

## the first bit of s:
# s
# Out[116]: 
# <script type="application/ld+json">
# {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","numberOfItems":50,
```

What I've tried:

- randomly perusing through methods with tab completion on `s`.
- picking through the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag).

My problem is that `s` only has 1 attribute (`type`) and doesn't seem to have any child tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `s.text` to get the content of the script. It's JSON, so you can then just parse it with `json.loads`. From there, it's simple dictionary access:

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab&sort=p'
r = requests.get(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')

urls = [el['url'] for el in json.loads(s.text)['itemListElement']]

print(urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

More easy:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab&sort=p'
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

s = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')

# JUST THIS
json = json.loads(s.string)
```