# Parsing brackets in HTML with Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to parse some information thats in a var meta window, and I am just a little confused how to grab just the value for the "id".

My code is below

```
url = input("\n\nEnter URL: ")
print(Fore.MAGENTA + "\nSetting link . .  .")


def printID():
    print("")
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
form = soup.find('script', {'id' : 'ProductJson-product-template'})
scripts = soup.findAll('id')

#get the id
'''
for scripts in form:
    data = soup.find_all()
    print data
    '''

print(form)

printID()
```

And the output of this prints

```
<script id="ProductJson-product-template" type="application/json">
    {"id":463448473639,"title":"n/a","handle":"n/a","description":"n/a"}
  </script>
```

Again, I just want to print just the value of the ID ("463448473639").

Comment: That’s JSON, and Python has [a handy `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961094/8150371

Answer (score 2):

you can retrieve all the attributes using following sytax.

```
form.attrs
```

and if you looking some specific, it's dictionary.

```
form['id']
```

the full code is as below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc="""<script id="ProductJson-product-template" type="application/json">
    {"id":463448473639,"title":"n/a","handle":"n/a","description":"n/a"}
  </script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print soup.find("script").attrs
print soup.find("script")['id']
```

However if you want to get value of ID from innerText        `{"id":463448473639,"title":"n/a","handle":"n/a","description":"n/a"}`
the only way to do is, as below.

```
innerText = soup.find("script").getText()
print innerText
print ast.literal_eval(strip(innerText)).get("id")
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but my OP should of been more clear,  I am trying to print just the value of the "id" inside the bracket "463448473639". I am looking to print just that value

Comment: and how this is not solving your issue.  Please read the Bs4 docs online and it would be much clear

Comment: Because your script prints "ProductJson-product-template", not "463448473639"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are going to want to do something like:

```
import json
id = json.loads(scripts[0].get_text())['id']
```

I haven't tested that but if you want to get what is in between the script tags I think that is they way you will do it. [get_text doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)